# Retrieve Blogs by UserID using Auth2.0 Token (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, google-api, blogger

I'm currency creating a Local Hosted Server (Using WAMP Server) to Manage My Blog Post.

I could able to retrieve Auth2.0 Token, but how to send the HTTP request with Auth2.0 Token?

When I use `XMLHttpRequest` with `xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token);`, I get an error

> 403: PERMISSION_DENIED

Code:

```
function get_token(clientID, redirectURI) {
    let client = new jso.JSO({
        providerID: "google",
        client_id: clientID,
        redirect_uri: redirectURI,
        authorization: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
        scopes: { request: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger"] }
    });
    client.callback();
    client.getToken()
        .then((token) => {
            console.log("I got the token : ", token)
            viewblogs(token['access_token'])
        })
}

function viewblogs(token) {
    // How to get blog list by userID?
}

get_token(
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'http://127.0.0.1/API/Auth2.0/'
);
```

Here is the Google Developer Docs but there is no example code to how to do it with JavaScript
https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#RetrievingAUsersBlogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Token is a JWT token so you should add `Bearer` before writing the token.

Try this:

```
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+token);
```